# Add multiple vertical lines in stacked bar chart

Tags: excel, charts

I'm trying to create a timeline in Excel that also has multiple vertical lines with labels calling out specific days on the timeline.  I created a timeline using a stacked bar chart outlined in the article below.  I've included the image extracted from the article showing what a simple timeline looks like.

[image]

https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/timeline-chart-in-excel/

I'm stuck on adding multiple vertical lines with labels to the above chart.  I've tried creating combo charts, but when I add another chart type the data is always plotted on the secondary axis and not the primary, which has the dates.

The vertical lines should look similar to what is picture below, but overlaid on top of the timeline at specific dates.  The image was extracted from the following article under the section called "Instructions for creating an Excel timeline".

[image]

https://www.officetimeline.com/make-timeline/excel

Below is a simple mockup of the desired output using the drawing tools to add vertical lines to a stacked bar chart.  The final objective is to add the verticals lines as a chart type and not manually draw them.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide in solving this issue.

Comment: Please don't expect us to read articles and watch videos to understand what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: That you for taking a look at my question.  I edited it to make it easier to understand and so that you don't have to read the articles.  I had forgotten you can add images to the posts.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm confused. What kind of chart do you want to create? Mock up the desired results with the drawing tools and post a screenshot.

Comment: I edited the question and added a mockup of the desired output.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a combination chart, I assume that you use a Scatter chart to place the vertical lines? At least, that's what I would use.

The scatter chart will always be on the secondary axis. You cannot have two chart types on the same axis.

If the primary and secondary axes don't line up, format the secondary axis minimum and maximum values to be the same as the primary axis min and max. That's all it takes.

**Edit after desired chart screenshot posted in question:**

This can be done with an XY chart on the secondary axis. For the Y values use a 1 in all cases. For the X axis values use the dates you want to show. Add the data to the XY chart and ensure that there is only one series in the XY chart (check the data source dialog). You need to be in control here. If you let Excel use the defaults, it may result in the dates getting plotted as a series instead of being used in the X axis, so edit that data source dialog!!

Format the secondary Y axis, set the max to 1 and the min to 0. That means that your data point with date for X and 1 for Y will plot near the top of the Y axis.

For the secondary X axis, use the same min and max dates as you see in the primary axis. You may need to manipulate the defaults that Excel puts in automatically, i.e. you may need to edit the primary axis, too, and put in the same min and max values. That will align the two axes to show the same dates.

You only require only one data point per vertical line, because you can use error bars to create a drop line from the data point down to the X axis.

This is advanced charting with a lot of tricks, which maybe a bit overwhelming, but posting a full tutorial will be too much for this site. This answer should put you on the right track and give you the basic ideas on how to achieve this. You can then research these techniques and ask a new question if you need help with a detail of any of these techniques.

Comment: Yes, I tried the scatter plot.  The problem is that the dates for the stacked bar chart are on the x axis.  Event names are on the y axis.  When I add the scatter plot and select the dates it plots it on the y axis when I need them to align on the x axis.  I hope this adds some clarity.

Comment: Weeeeellll, XY can plot any number on any axis, really. Just flip the X and Y values, no?

Comment: Thanks for the mock-up. I have now added a description on how to achieve this result.

Comment: I eventually got it to work after a lot of trial and error.  I copied the XY data and used the paste special method to add the data to the stacked bar chart.  For some reason I was forced to make the stacked bar chart the secondary series otherwise it would swap the axis on the bar chart.  Thank you for your help and patience.